Weak Equality & Strong Equality?
I have been trying to understand the meaning of these concepts: Weak $(\approx)$ and Strong $(=)$ Equality in the Dirac-Bergmann Algorithm for Hamiltonian Constrained Systems. I have already read Henneaux and Teitelboim's Quantization of Gauge Systems, and also Brown's Singular Lagrangians, Constrained Hamiltonian Systems and Gauge Invariance: An Example of the Dirac-Bergmann Algorithm.  In addition, the Wikipedia article about it, and the answers in: Strong equality in Quantization of Gauge Systems by Henneaux and Teitelboim and About constraints of the first class and electrodynamics, and kind of helped. Nevertheless, My comprehension of this is still vague.
In those references, there are said things like the followings:

Two functions $F$, $G$ that coincide on the submanifold defined by the constraint $\phi_j \approx 0$ are said to be weaky equal, and one writes $F \approx G$. On the other hand, an equation that holds throughout the phase space and not just on the submanifold $\phi_j \approx 0$ is called strong, and the usual equality symbol $=$ is used in that case.
Two functions on phase space, $F$ and $G$, are weakly equal if they are equal when the constraints are satisfied, but not throughout the phase space, denoted $F \approx G$. If $F$ and $G$ are equal independently of the constraints being satisfied, they are called strongly equal, written $F = G$. It is important to note that, in order to get the right answer, no weak equations may be used before evaluating derivatives or Poisson brackets.
Two functions in phase space $F$ and $G$ are weakly equal if they are identical up to the equations of motion, also denoted by on shell. If $F$ and $G$ are equal on shell, then $F=G$, and they are said to be strongly equal.

It would be really good if you can help me to understand it by explanations (geometrical/intuitive) but also by a variety of simple examples (specially). It would really help and will contribute to my comprehension.

You haven't really asked a specific question here - what exactly do you not understand here? Your first and second bullet point are the same (you just replaced "$\phi_j = 0$" by "the constraints are satisfied", but the constraints being satisfied just means that the constraints are zero), and I don't understand where the third point comes from - which reference uses "weak" and "strong" as synonyms for "on-shell" and "off-shell"?

I don't think it is that hard to understand that I would like to receive a well thought out and broken down explanation about what these concepts are, and the difference between them; If able, using examples to explain. On the other hand, I listed some of the Definitions given in those references. The first one corresponds to Quantization of Gauge Systems, the seconde one to Brown's Article, and the third one to Wikipedia.
